# PHP: Check whether an HTML element has a certain class

Tags: php, html

I'd like to present links to similar topics at the end of of a blog entry. My strategy would be to quote the topic tag as class attribute to the html or body element:

```
<html class="bears honey alaska">
```

And make a simple PHP function at the bottom of the page: "If  has class 'bears', include bears.php here." Without any elses.

Could someone help me with the code?

The data-attribute in HTML 5 might be more appropriate for that, but I don't know if PHP can address them.

Thanks.
Runa

Comment: how are you giving your html those classes? Statically? If so, you will need to use something like jQuery ajax to call php and fetch data. PHP is server side and processes before output, so you can't expect it to react to something already written to the DOM.

Comment: As you're trying to do this from PHP-side, there's not much difference between `class` or `data-` attributes, both are equally inefficient. Those would require reading the OB and using a DOM parser/ugly regexes. You'd be much better using variables, a global array would take care of it easily.

Comment: @KaiQing Ajax is independant and has **nothing** to do with jQuery.

Comment: @sebas - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ - that. makes life easier. I know the difference. But if he google searches "jquery ajax" at his level he is much more likely to resolve his problem than if he were to just search for ajax.

Comment: @KaiQing I understand the pedagogic intention but I have to disapprove. The trend of systematically using frameworks to realise simple javascript tasks goes against my education and my values. (In the case of ajax, jquery actually complicates it in my opinion) My disapproval does not mean I don't respect your opinion.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of checking the classes in PHP, I would use PHP to define the classes and then print it into the HTML

```
<?php
$tags = array('bears', 'honey', 'alaska');
?>
<html class="<?=implode(' ', $tags)?>">
```

and in the end you can

```
if(in_array('bears', $tags)) include("bears.php");
```

or if you want to include a file with the same name for each tag:

```
foreach($tags as $tag) include($tag.".php");
```

The latter will require you to ensure you have a file for each. Alternatively, more complex solutions (such as classes) might prove to be more useful in the long run.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. The array didn't come to my mind. It's the better way and your code works.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of the classes you want to include in PHP, before writing the page :

```
$classes = array('bears', 'honey', 'alaska');
```

Once you actually need to print classes in the html tag, you can do something like this :

Then later in the code, you can do the following thing :

```
if (in_array("bears", $classes)
{
    // your code here
}
```

This will make it easy for you to add more classes later on, all you will need to do is add another one to your array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with regular expressions, like this:

```
$html_string = '<html class="bears honey alaska">';
$class = 'bears';
$has_bears = preg_match('/<html class="[^"]*'.$class.'[^"]*">/', $html_string);
if ($has_bears) {
    include('bears.php');
}
```

That said, I strongly urge you to read the other comments to your question. What you want to do doesn't really sound like an ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

If (and you will need to clarify if this is the case) you are using *only* PHP then the code is all executed server-side. There is no need to add classes, and you cannot detect them since the DOM is not yet created. Simply store your topics in a variable, eg. an array:

```
$myTopics = ["bears","honey","alaska"];
```

Then you can check later in the page if a given value is in your array of topics:

```
if( in_array( "bears", $myTopics ) {
  doStuff();
}
```

If you're using separate files to build the page you may need to declare and retrieve $myTopics as a global variable in order to use it later on.